# Unknown chili pepper, any one know?

Tags: identification

The chili plant has smallish leaves, current height about 1 & half feet tall. The chili pepper is probably half the size of a golf ball, green turning to red. Any ideas what type it is please?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Scotch Bonnet

Alternate Names: Bonney peppers, ball of fire peppers, cachucha and Caribbean red peppers

i just planted some seeds :)

Comment: Yep, definitely a cultivar of Capsicum Chinensis. You may not get a definite identification beyond that, but it includes habaneros, Scotch Bonnet, etc.